# how to add sliding transition to pages(different text and image in each page) in same widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I was trying to implement my own AppTour it works fine, but I wanted to to add a slide transition in which the previous page slides from right to left and leaves screen viewport and next screen enters screen from outside the viewport(from right to left) . As the name suggested I read about SlideTransition and it is working with a single widget, I am confused how could I chain it to my multipple pages. My page changes are done by setState and my old page is replaced with new page just by changing image and text and selectedIndex. How should I achieve slide transition of current page leaving the screen and next page entering the screen at same time. Till now what I have made is given below. It is a working example of what I am able to acheive till yet and here is the link to codepen as well https://codepen.io/nimishbansal/pen/RwrjdNN
(note:increase editor size in codepen to get look at mobile ui portrait version)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: AppInitialTour(),
    );
  }
}

const skipTourForTesting = true;

class _TourScreen {
  final String text;
  final String imagePath;

  _TourScreen({this.text, this.imagePath});
}

/// Pages for the screens thar are displayed in app tour.
List<_TourScreen> _pages = [
  _TourScreen(text: "Page 1", imagePath: 'https://www.clker.com/cliparts/G/O/f/1/7/n/number-1-hi.png'),
  _TourScreen(text: "Page 2", imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/NYCS-bull-trans-2.svg/1024px-NYCS-bull-trans-2.svg.png'),
  _TourScreen(text: "Page 3", imagePath: 'https://webstockreview.net/images/3-clipart-three-2.png')
];

/// App tour that is shown once user launches the app for the first time.
class AppInitialTour extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppInitialTourState createState() => _AppInitialTourState();
}

class _AppInitialTourState extends State<AppInitialTour> {
  int _selectedIndex = 1;

  int _totalItems = 3;

  List<Image> imageWidgets = [];

  @override
  void initState(){
    for(var page in _pages){
      imageWidgets.add(Image.network(page.imagePath),);
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    for(var im in imageWidgets){
      precacheImage(im.image, context);
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var _screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var _buttonTextStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.grey[600]);
    var _imageWidth = 0.75 * _screenWidth;
    var _imageHeight = 0.8 * _imageWidth;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: _screenWidth,
                height: 0.8 * _screenHeight,
                color: Color(0xFF45d6b9),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0.25 * _screenHeight,
                left: 0.12 * _screenWidth,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    width: _imageWidth,
                    height: _imageHeight,
                    child: Image.network(
                     _pages[_selectedIndex - 1].imagePath,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(_pages[_selectedIndex - 1].text),
            ],
          ),

          // Current Index Indicator
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (int i = 1; i <= _totalItems; i++)
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  width: 12,
                  height: 12,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      color: i == _selectedIndex
                          ? Color(0xFF45d6b9)
                          : Colors.white,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle),
                )
            ],
          ),

          SizedBox(
            height: 0.04 * _screenHeight,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              _selectedIndex < _totalItems
                  ? FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Skip',
                        style: _buttonTextStyle,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )
                  : Container(),
              Spacer(),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  _selectedIndex < _totalItems ? 'Next' : 'Done',
                  style: _buttonTextStyle,
                ),
                onPressed: _selectedIndex < _totalItems
                    ? () {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedIndex += 1;
                        });
                      }
                    : () => _handleOnTapDone(context),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleOnTapDone(BuildContext context) {
    print("end");
  }
}
```

How could I achieve such a sliding effect like this [image: Text]

Comment: Use a `PageView`.

Comment: ok thanks, let me give it a try. Can you tell me one more thing that was I heading in wrong direction(when I was exploring SlideTransition)

Comment: You could have use what you were doing with a `Stack` or something, but it would be much more work with worse performance.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherMoore the page view worked for me perfectly